# Spring Boot - int in property file getting read as String?

Tags: spring-boot, property-files

In my application.properties file, I have a line that says

```
variablename=1000
```

I then read it in a class with

```
 @Value("${variablename}")
 private int variablename;
```

Or with

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class ClassName
```

This gets me an error, telling me that I can't convert from String to int, except I'm not converting to int as far as I'm aware.

Error is:

Failed to bind properties under 'variablename' to int:

Property:variablename
Value: 1000
Origin: class path resource [application.properties]:21:8
Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to int

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Check there isn't any trailing whitespace after the value.

Comment: Added the error

Comment: Why does your stack trace say the value is 50 when you are showing that you are trying to set it 1000?  I suspect we're not getting the full picture here.

Comment: which version spring boot ?

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, modified the value after asking the question/ before the edit.

Comment: Okay, accidentally solved this; had left a stray semicolon somewhere in the properties file. Is there a way to close a question once it's solved?